# How to print all possible permutations of different lengths in python?

Tags: python, string, permutation

I am trying to print all possible permutations of a string of different lengths

I am doing

```py
def toString(List):
    return ''.join(List)


def permute(string1, l, r):
    if l == r:
        print(toString(string1))
    else:
        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            string1[l], string1[i] = string1[i], string1[l]
            permute(string1, l + 1, r)
            string1[l], string1[i] = string1[i], string1[l] 


string = "ABC"
n = len(string)
a = list(string)
permute(a, 0, n-1)
```

but it returns
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB

I want it to return
A, B, C, AB, BC, AC, ABC, ACB, BAC etc.

I am unable to achieve that

Comment: have you tried itertools.permutations?

Comment: I am trying to do it without using any modules but i'll try it with that too, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: @RISHABHAGRAWAL
I guess you actually need all subsets of the string, not permutations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for all possible subsets of the string and not permutations if so then you can use any one of the following approaches which look intuitive to you

```
def permute(string1):
    n = len(string1)
    finalSet = ['']

    def permutation(size, cur, k):
        if len(cur) == size:
            finalSet.append(''.join(cur))
            return

        for j in range(k, n):
            permutation(size, cur + [string1[j]], j+1)

    for i in range(1, n):
        permutation(i, [], 0)

    finalSet.append(string1)

    return finalSet


print(permute("ABC"))
# Output : ['', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'AB', 'AC', 'BC', 'ABC']
```

Another approach which uses binary data to create subsets

```
# Short and simple approach
def permute(string1):
    superSet = []
    n = len(string1)

    for i in range(2**n, 2**(n+1)):
        seq = [x for x in bin(i)[3:]]
        superSet.append(''.join([string1[j]
                                 for j in range(n) if seq[j] == '1']))

    return superSet


print(permute("ABC"))
# Output : ['', 'C', 'B', 'BC', 'A', 'AC', 'AB', 'ABC']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you just have to wrap one more for loop around `permutate` and use your function to calculate permutation of all substrings:

```
def toString(List):
    return ''.join(List)


def permute(string1, l, r):
    if l == r and r != 0:
        print(toString(string1))
    else:
        for i in range(l, r + 1):
            string1[l], string1[i] = string1[i], string1[l]
            permute(string1, l + 1, r)
            string1[l], string1[i] = string1[i], string1[l]


my_string = "ABC"
for s in my_string:
    print(s)
for i,_ in enumerate(my_string):
    n = len(my_string[:i+1])
    a = list(my_string[:i+1])
    permute(a, 0, n-1)
```

Comment: but this prints A
AB
BA
ABC
ACB
BAC
BCA
CBA
CAB